# How to read the nameplate of an air conditioner?

Tags: electrical, cables

What's the difference between the two currents (The 25A and the 11.2A)?
Which one is used to calculate the cross-section area of the supply cable?

What is the **Cooling Rated Input**?
Is it used to calculate the cross-section area of the supply cable?

The **Cooling Rated Current** = 2415W / 220V = 10.97A. But in fact, It's higher than that. Is that because of the apparent power (the power factor)?

If I used the equation: **P = V * I * Power Factor**, The power factor = 0.98.

I think the power factor of an air conditioner is lower than that!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that symbol and the 25A is the size of the fuse.

The fuse is rated for the starting current, the 11A is the current in normal running.

Edit after Tom Carpenter’s comment:
You should size the cables for at least 25A and a better capacity would not hurt if the cable run is long.

Comment: If by « automatic » you mean a miniature circuit breaker or residual current device, then yes.

Comment: Why should I size the cable for 15A not 11.2A? Just for safety?

Comment: Safety and reducing losses. Saving a few coins with a small cable is false economy...

Comment: If the fuse is rated for 25A, and the fuse is there to protect the wiring, the wiring should surely be rated for 25A.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter Does that mean the fuse is protecting the cable only (Not the air conditioner)? I mean if there's a fault in the air conditioner (let's say it consumes 20A instead of 11.2A), the CB will not trip and the AC will wear out, right?

Comment: @MichaelGeorge the purpose of fuses is to stop the cabling melting its insulation, shorting out, and burning the house down. The unit itself should have some other internal thermal and/or electrical protection for itself.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter. Wow thank you so much. Those are very useful comments.

Comment: Your starting current (LRA) is 72A, which is 6.4 or 7 times your full-load current.  It's why your fuse is larger and probably slow blow.